# In PL/SQL, I want to declare a cursor within cursor. The second cursor should use a value from the first cursor in "FROM clause". How can I do this?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to read the values from one `cursor` to another in the `FROM` Clause.
Below is the code snippet.

```
/* First Cursor to getTable Name*/

Cursor Get_Table_Nm IS    
Select code_val1_nm from ref_table_detail where CODE_VAL2_NM=V_Table_Name


/*Second Cursor to update the id*/

CURSOR SEQ_UPDT IS  
SELECT V_Table_Name_Intrl_Id, V_Table_Name_Seq_Id 
FROM (<<<<<Here I Want to pass the value from Get_Table_Nm (first) Cursor>>>>);
```

Comment: Apologies for TYPO... Its PLSQL

Answer (score 0):

Here the `cursor_1` returning a `table name` that needs to be used in the `second cursor`

You have to use the `dynamic cursor`

```
DECLARE       
    Cursor Get_Table_Nm IS    
    Select code_val1_nm 
    from ref_table_detail 
    where CODE_VAL2_NM = V_Table_Name;

    SEQ_UPDT SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_code_val1_nm varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    OPEN Get_Table_Nm;
    LOOP 
        FETCH Get_Table_Nm INTO  v_code_val1_nm;
        EXIT WHEN Get_Table_Nm%NOTFOUND;

        open SEQ_UPDT 
        for 'SELECT V_Table_Name_Intrl_Id, V_Table_Name_Seq_Id FROM ' || v_code_val1_nm;

        LOOP
            -- Fetch SEQ_UPDT into ....
            -- Do with the data
        END LOOP;
        close SEQ_UPDT

    END LOOP;
    close Get_Table_Nm;
END;
```

Comment: Yes.. i did try that.. instead of going for 2 cusors i tried reading the table name directly in FROM clause.. There is no compilation error but no data is being updated. i guess it's because select in FROM clause returns dataset which we cannot use as a table name... i did it this way... Suggest if you see some changes required.. Remember it is returning a table name from where i will fetch actual data          CURSOR SEQ_UPDT IS  
SELECT V_Table_Name_Intrl_Id, V_Table_Name_Seq_Id FROM (select code_val1_nm from ref_table_detail where CODE_VAL2_NM=V_Table_Name);

Comment: you are selecting `V_Table_Name_Intrl_Id, V_Table_Name_Seq_Id` from a collection containing only `code_val1_nm`. (Error!!!)

Comment: code_val1 will return a table name for me which has V_Table_Name_Intrl_Id, V_Table_Name_Seq_Id as columns... i think we cannot directly consider the subquery o/p as a table name then select from it. that's why looking for 2 seperate cursors

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open a cursor on different tables, depending on the result of a query, you can try with dynamic SQL; for example something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
DECLARE
    V_Table_Name                varchar2(30);
    V_Table_For_Second_Query    varchar2(30);
    ...
BEGIN
    ...       
    Select code_val1_nm 
    into V_Table_For_Second_Query
    from ref_table_detail 
    where CODE_VAL2_NM=V_Table_Name;

    open cursor SEQ_UPDT for 
        'SELECT V_Table_Name_Intrl_Id, V_Table_Name_Seq_Id ' ||
        'FROM ' ||
        V_Table_For_Second_Query;
    ...
```